# Why would shutdown immediately after creating newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor?

Tags: java, executorservice, project-reactor

[projectreactor 3.3.1](https://projectreactor.io/docs) have the class `reactor.core.scheduler.ElasticScheduler` which contains this code:

```java
this.exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
this.exec.shutdownNow();
```

Why would one do this?

[An ExecutorService can be shut down, which will cause it to reject new tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) so the above created [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) would become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the above created ScheduledExecutorService would become useless.

Useless if you actually wanted to submit tasks to it to be executed, yes.

> Why would one do this?

Quite simply, to obtain an executor service that *always* rejects new tasks submitted to it, never executing any of them. In the current implementation of `ElasticScheduler`, it's used for the `SHUTDOWN` field, which is the `CachedService` returned by the `pick()` method after the enclosing scheduler is disposed.

In this use case therefore it makes perfect sense, as you explicitly don't want any new tasks to be scheduled after `dispose()` is called.